# How to remove contents from js file and render it from a xml file in react application?

Tags: reactjs

In my react application,I have HTML content in js file,but I need to make it external and render this from a XML file.
How can we achieve this.Please share some references or documentation.

Comment: so load an xml file and read the data?

Answer (score 0):

Convert XML to JSON and use in react .
[try this XML TO JSON PACKAGE](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js)